# NETCONF - IOS XE - 16.04.01 cli-config-data throws error

Tags: network-programming, sdn, cisco-ios, ietf-netconf

I am trying to execute CLI commands using NETONF RPC in IOS XE 16.04.01. I got the schema for the NETCONF RPC from the device CLI "show netconf schema". Below is the schema specific to edit-config,

```
<edit-config> [0, 1] required
<target> 1 required
<candidate> [0, 1] required
<running> [0, 1] required
<startup> [0, 1] required
<url> [0, 1] required
<default-operation> [0, 1] required
<test-option> [0, 1] required
<error-option> [0, 1] required
<config> 1 required
<cli-config-data> [0, 1] required
<cmd> 1+ required
<cli-config-data-block> [0, 1] required
```

is seen in the schema. I tried to execute the below RPC but it throws error as cli-config-data. How to execute CLI commands using NETCONF for IOS XE?

## RPC request

```
<rpc message-id="2323" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
<edit-config>
<target>
<running/>
</target>
<config>
<cli-config-data>
<cmd>hostname CSR1000V</cmd>
</cli-config-data>
</config>
</edit-config>
</rpc>
```

## RPC reply

```
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="2323">
<rpc-error>
<error-type>protocol</error-type>
<error-tag>unknown-element</error-tag>
<error-severity>error</error-severity>
<error-path>
/rpc/edit-config/config
</error-path>
<error-info>
<bad-element>cli-config-data</bad-element>
</error-info>
</rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `cli-config-data` and `cmd` elements belong to a namespace that is not `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0`, which is reserved for the NETCONF messages layer.

Comment: which namespace to be used for <cli-config-data>?

Answer (score 1):

In IOS-XE you have the option to enable `netconf ssh` or `netconf-yang` in the configuration - I made the mistake of enabling `netconf-yang` and then tried to use `cli-config-data-block` as I assumed it was valid as I saw it in `show netconf schema`.

If you enable `netconf-yang` then it expects a valid YANG model, but `netconf ssh` enables legacy NETCONF support which uses the schema as output by `show netconf schema`. Once you enable `netconf ssh` then the following can be sent to the device to update the configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rpc xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="100">
  <edit-config>
    <target>
      <running/>
    </target>
    <config>
      <cli-config-data-block>
        hostname test
      </cli-config-data-block>
    </config>
  </edit-config>
</rpc>
```

I just now need to work out how to send multiline strings as the following doesn't work and there isn't a valid YANG model for this under IOS-XE:

```
menu test title $
this is a title
$
```